# Improving Security of .txt Files in C++

Tags: c++, security

I've written a program that appends user input text to existing .txt file.  There is also a function that reserves the text in the original .txt file and saves the reversed characters to a different .txt file. How can I improve the security of my code?

I've tried using string instead of char to avoid buffer overflow--but I had trouble compiling the rest of the code with that variable type.

```
void reverseFile()
{
    //creates new file to write reversed .txt

    fstream newFile;
    newFile.open("otherfile.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);

    //constructs variable and pointer for original .txt file
    const char* const file = "otherfile.txt";

    string formatText;

    //reads the characters from the file into a string
    {
        fstream changeFile(file);

        char c;

        while (changeFile.get(c))

            formatText += c;
    }

    // reverse the string
    reverse(formatText.begin(), formatText.end());

    // print reversed string to the new file

    newFile << formatText << endl;

    newFile.close();
}

int main()
{

    char inputText[500];

    //opens file for creating, writing and reading
    fstream file;

    //opens file to read an append
    file.open("file.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);

    //asks user for input and appends that to file

    cout << "Enter text to append to file" << endl;
    cin.getline(inputText, sizeof(inputText));

    file << inputText << endl;

    reverseFile();
}
```

Full disclosure--this is a homework assignment and the code functions as intended.  I am looking for advice from more experienced programmers for my own curiosity on how to improve my code to make it more secure.

Comment: Offhand I didn't see any syntax errors that would cause problems, but I didn't try feeding it into a compiler. Generally speaking, the errors from the compiler make sense, but if they don't, you can Google the text of the message, and it might give you better descriptions. I would definitely use string instead of char inputText[500]. You'll find some methods can take strings instead of char arrays but you might drop the size field, for instance. Or you might have to read some docs to find a method that works better.

Comment: One more comment: optional {} shouldn't be optional. Professional coding standards  tell you to avoid this because it's a well-known and very common error. So if (condition) { foo(); } never if (condition) foo(); Yes, for one-line statements, you can skip the {}, but it WILL haunt you if you do so.

Comment: Hi Joseph--  Thank you.  I am working to change my code to include a string variable instead of char.  Is there a way to include the spaces in a string for c++?  I'm finding the file will only append the first word n a sentence without my defining the character length--and if I define the character length with a string--I'm back at the original problem, right?

Comment: `std::string` can take spaces just fine. The problem is that the `<<` operator that you're probably using stops reading when it encounters any whitespace. Use `std::getline()` (the free function, not `cin.getline()`).